# Iex pry going step by step?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-iex

I want to use IEx.pry to go step by step in my elixir code, like byebug in ruby or debug point in Java. I tried looking into the documentation here : https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4f68c4f10502e0f54a21093bb9a33957e63a9ac4/lib/iex/lib/iex.ex
but did not find anything. Could anyone suggest a way to do this ?

Comment: Maybe you will find this useful: https://github.com/qhool/quaff

Comment: @PatrickOscity, I usually work on a remote machine. Is there a way to run the quaff tool in command line only ?

Comment: @VoodooChild: You can use `ssh -Y` when you ssh into your remote machine so any window will be redirected to your host machine.

Answer (score 15):

It is not possible as pry is not a debugger. Pry simply allows you to interact with a particular context.

Comment: If pry isn't the answer to setting a breakpoint and stepping through a running Elixir program, what is?

Comment: @sma , as Patrick pointed out, github.com/qhool/quaff is a tool which you can use

Comment: Can't believe I did not know about quaff until now. Thansk @sma

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping for a way to step through Elixir code via `IEx.pry` as well, but that's not possible. Erlang does have a debugger that you can use for Elixir code.

You can start the debugger by running: `:debugger.start()`

I learned about it here: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/04/debugging-techniques-in-elixir-lang/

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers pointed out, pry does not offer this functionality.

As a workaround you could add multiple `IEx.pry` instructions, inspect and use `continue` to go to the next one.

Comment: `continue` is used to continue the execution, the question is about `step` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

After elixir 1.14, you can use the [next/0](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.14.0/IEx.Helpers.html#next/0) function after setting a breakpoint on the function you wanna debug.

To se a breakpoint you need to enter your `iex` terminal and use the function  [break!/2](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/1.14.0/IEx.Helpers.html#break!/2) and pass the function and the arity, so said function receives a breakpoint. Like this:

```
break! MyModule.function_to_be_debugged/2
```

And then, when you call said function, you will be able to debug it, line by line with the `next/0`